# Xcode Debugger Crashes (Xcode 6.1 / LLDB / Yosemite)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

My Xcode debugger is crashing most of the time if I call "po" on variables or expressions in the Swift language

Is anyone else experiencing this issue or found a workaround?

It's an iOS project, iOS 8.1 target and I believe otherwise default settings... Surely I'm not the only one?

Comment: With all those bugs with the Swift compiler, screw the debugger I say. Swift development in Xcode 6.1 is not plausible right now. My humble suggestion to you is to switch to Objective-C for now.

Comment: file a bug report: https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

Steps to avoid the crash :

1. Try to exit fullscreen mode in Xcode and run your app again. It was crashing for me when Xcode was in fullscreen mode.
2. This issue can occur if you are building your project against the iOS 8.x SDKs and are weak linking a framework that is new to iOS 8.x and also present in OS X 10.10 and you run in the iOS 7.1 simulator.

The Xcode 6.1 [Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html) mentioned these issues.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not specifically doing any weak linking. I am trying to run using iOS 7 though. And not in full screen... So I guess my debugger issue is something aside from those two ideas?